# How to fetch frames with Jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <frameset cols="180,590,*" border="0">  
        <frame src="test.html" name="main" noresize="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frame src="http://www.test.com/my.php" name="right" noresize="" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            #document    <!-- what is this? -->
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>TEST</title>
                    </head>
                    <body></body>
                </html>
        </frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I'm parsing a webpage. But I have a problem with it. 
What is the `#documnet`? 
And how can I parse `<html>` below `#document` using `Jsoup`?

Comment: You can read about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does #document mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474605/what-does-document-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And how can I parse  below #document using Jsoup?

You can see `#document` as a "virtual" element. Jsoup won't see it. It is not present in the actual HTML code neither.

What you want is fetching the frames with Jsoup. See below:

```
Document doc = ...; // HTML page containing the frameset

Document mainFrameDocument = Jsoup.connect(doc.select("frame[name=main]").absUrl("src")).get();

Document rightFrameDocument = Jsoup.connect(doc.select("frame[name=right]").absUrl("src")).get();
```