# How to get the html document contained inside an HTML tag using selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to get the source code of HTML document which is inside an HTML tag which is generated after some JavaScript and store it in a variable. Here, the HTML tag is `<iframe>` and it contains a variable kind of something that looks like `#document` and when I expand this, I get an HTML document which looks something like `<!DOCTYPE html> <html>...</html>`

**To summarize:**

```
<iframe src="https://www.XXXXXX.com/" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="yes" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>...</html>  // a whole new HTML document
</iframe>
```

I want to store all the content of this HTML document as a string in python

**What I have done:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/path/to/iframe/tag').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

but, this just returns an empty string. Also, I have checked if it is working with BeautifulSoup

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())
```

but, this also isn't working

**NOTE:** I run these test only after the script is executed, also, I guess the problem seems to be with the `#document` thing

Comment: What about fetching the url of the iframe and then again call driver.get with that url. See Scott also suggested this and he also provided a code snippet.

Comment: You can't get ```iframe```'s ```innerHTML```, you have to redirect to it's ```src```

Comment: Is the iframe of interest present in the initial response as this is not always the case - then you won't be able to extract src from response to make next request - though you can manually take the src from webpage and issue against that.

Comment: @QHarr it is present in the initial response, but redirecting to it's src is not that helpful... anyways, I got the answer by switching the driver's frame

Comment: Doh.... should have said that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple,
I just switched from current frame to the frame of `<iframe>` element

Code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get iframe content by using `innerHTML`, as you can't do it even with javascript inside a self made html document, like so:

```js
function Button(){
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    p.innerHTML = "Result of iframe.innerHTML: " + iframe.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://bing.com/"></iframe>
<br>
<button onclick="Button();">Click me to alert innerHTML</button>
<p></p>
```

Instead, you want to **redirect to iframe's `src`** and get html content.

Didn't test the following code but i hope it helps you.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_path, firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('https://example.com/')
documentText = driver.page_source

soup =  BeautifulSoup(documentText)
iframe_source = soup.find('iframe')['src']

driver.get(iframe_source)

documentText = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(documentText)
html = soup.find('html')

print(html.content)
```

Comment: I tried testing the code you provided, but since the src URL is not permissible to access, the code fails... but I found my answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a `HTML document` in an html document? I do think this isn't possible, but you could try putting an HTLM document on a different site and than by using `<iframe src="www.html-content.com"></iframe>`

Comment: There is also a way with using `jQuery`. For this i would suggest you look on this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I don't want to include an html file in an html file, instead, I have the page source of a webpage, means, it is already given to me... Can you elaborate more on that #document variable? I'm seeing it for the first time, due to which I am unable to get the html code which is inside it

Comment: @ArihantBedagkar document is a virtual element, which doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @ArihantBedagkar more about ```#document``` on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474605/what-does-document-mean

Comment: @Scott the link you provided worked for me like a charm! The only thing to do was to switch the driver to the new frame. Thanks a lot!