# How to traverse Virtual DOM using Javascipt in browser's console?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, virtual-dom

Recently i was trying to traverse the DOM in Google Chrome's console.[image: cant traverse inside #document]

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.g-recaptcha>div>div'); 
console.log(list)
```

i don't know how to go inside #document. Please someone help. [Found this article about #document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474605/what-does-document-mean)

But the link i provided is of #document problem in selenium web driver. I am not using selenium web driver and I just want to know how can i traverse the #document using css selector or anyother javascript  solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: I know knothing about Jquery. Only know pure javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript -----> this link suggest to first get the iframe by queryselector 
let that be, 
       var iframe = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha>div>div>[title]');
and then use iframe.contentDocument and iframe.contentWindow.document

in case of iframe.contentDocument it's returning null and in case of iframe.contentWindow.document it's giving the error --> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://iqfaucet.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: The cross origin issue is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/364997/2181514 which essentially just points to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: But that didn't give any solution in pure javascript.

Comment: then what i should do?

Comment: TBH, probably not the best explained question/answer - try this question, with a lot more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame